# How to enable GPU support in Python/TensorFlow project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow, gpu

I have installed Python (Anaconda 4.4.0) in Visual Studio 2017, and run the Neural-Style example from https://github.com/anishathalye/neural-style using the CPU verson of the TensorFlow package.

I am trying to re-run the example after installing the TensorFlow-GPU package (having installed CUDA and CuDNN), but I cannot seem to get Visual Studio/Python to acknowledge the tensorflow-gpu package.

If I **just** install the gpu package, the interpreter halts execution at the `import tensorflow as tf` line, reporting that the import could not be found.

Is there a runtime flag, or some modification to the code required to get Python to use the CUDA enabled version of TensorFlow?

[Visual Studio 2017, Python project using TensorFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsCEo.png)

Comment: do you have only one python version on your machine ?

Comment: No, actually (it seems) that Visual Studio installed 3 environments that I can switch between. If you click the link at the bottom you will see I have Python 3.5 and Python 3.6 as well as Anaconda 4.4. I selected Anaconda as it came with all the other dependencies I needed, like numpy.

Comment: I think it installed to another vrsion of pyhon than Anaconda. I bumped this couple of times. It may depend on PATH variable, which defines pip location.

Comment: Thanks - I will take a look tonight, I did notice that Visual Studio shows both the GPU and CPU packages installed under Anaconda, but this could be wrong. (It also shows an option to install the GPU option - even thought it is already installed).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I was going to avoid bothering with Anaconda and just use Visual Studio but if I need that I guess I'll use it instead.